# gdal2tiles generating nosensical data

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdal2tiles

I'm trying to convert a global irradiance map - generated by r.sun - into tiles to be layered onto OpenLayers using gdal2tiles.  However, every single one of my outputs is turning into white noise and I can't seem to find the issue.

The output images all look something along the lines of this, no matter the resolution:

[image: gdal2tiles 0 output]

The command QGIS is running is

```bash
gdal2tiles.bat -p raster -w openlayers "D:\\Google Drive\\Tucson_Sol\\14S14E07_3ft\\global\\monthly\\total_sun_apr_sum.tif" "D:\\Google Drive\\Tucson Solar Map\\OpenStreetMap Tiles\\14S14E07_3ft\\January\\dem"
```

and the output has no issues:

```
Algorithm gdal2tiles starting...
GDAL command:
cmd.exe /C gdal2tiles.bat -p raster -w openlayers "D:\\Google Drive\\Tucson_Sol\\14S14E07_3ft\\global\\monthly\\total_sun_apr_sum.tif" "D:\\Google Drive\\Tucson Solar Map\\OpenStreetMap Tiles\\14S14E07_3ft\\January\\dem" 
GDAL command output:
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done. 
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90..Generating Base Tiles: 
Generating Overview Tiles: 
.100 - done. 
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm gdal2tiles finished
```

Has anyone run into an issue like this?

Answer (score 1):

Im running into a similar issue.  Using ArcGIS, I exported a TIFF, then in the OSGeo4W shell, I ran:

> gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 -of vrt mosaic1988bw.tif mosyonv.vrt
>
> gdal2tiles mosyonv.vrt 1988_bw_aerials

It turned out that if my input raster is 16-bits, the tiles gdal2tiles produces suffer from digital noise as if Picaso cubed it up.  However, if I export an 8-bit (unsigned) TIFF, the resulting tiles look good.

This is not a perfect solution if you need a noData value outside of 0-255, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Rob's answer lead me on the right path on this one. Like you I was getting this bad output. It turned out that a 16bit input to gdal2tiles did not work well but translating it to 8bit in the band worked. In my case I had a single band grayscale SAR image. I used:

```
gdal_translate -b 1 -ot Byte input-filename.tif output-filename.tif
```

This changed the band type from UInt16 to Byte. I was then able to successfully run it though gdal2tiles to get a correct output.

You can check the band data type using gdalinfo.